# Py_DECREF on Temporary Variables in Functions

Tags: python, python-c-api

According to the accepted answer in [Py_INCREF/DECREF: When](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657764/py-incref-decref-when), Python objects that are created by functions but not explicitly returned should have their reference counts decremented via `DECREF`. Does this guideline apply to temporary variables? For example, I could use this:

```cpp
void PythonInterface::SetModule (const char *filename)
{
  PyObject *name = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault (filename);
  _module = PyImport_Import (name);
  Py_XDECREF (name);
}
```

or this:

```cpp
void PythonInterface::SetModule (const char *filename)
{
  _module = PyImport_Import (PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault (filename));
}
```

Are these two bits of code identical, or will the second example cause problems?

Comment: Temporary variables seem like a perfect example of an object that is created but not returned. I don't see why this would be an exception

Comment: This would imply that the second approach should be avoided, since we cannot explicitly decrement temporary variables. What about variable reassignments? Are these to be avoided as well?

Comment: Variable reassignments that take place within a function do not alter the issue.  Example 1 is still the correct way to manage python reference counts. fyi -- I assume `_module` is declared globally and intended to be kept past the life of `PythonInterface::SetModule` ?

Comment: Re: _module, yes. The idea is that I have a separate GetFunction () to return handles to the desired Python functions. I was hoping to reuse _module through the code; I'd SetModule (file1), then GetFunction (function1), then SetModule (file2), GetFunction (function2), etc. all to the same _module. Should I avoid this?