# How to return a cached PyObject* value several times without memory leaking or double/triple frees?

Tags: python, python-c-api

On my last question [How to improve Python C Extensions file line reading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56260096/how-to-improve-python-c-extensions-file-line-reading) was brought up some memory problems I had. Then, I wrote this simple and ridiculous usage of and Python C Extension, just with the purpose of trying to understanding better Python Borrowing and Owning References.

```cpp
static void PyFastFile_dealloc(PyFastFile* self) {
    for( PyObject* pyobject : linecache ) {
        Py_XDECREF( pyobject );
    }
    Py_TYPE(self)->tp_free( (PyObject*) self );
}

static PyObject* PyFastFile_tp_iter(PyFastFile* self, PyObject* args) {
    counter = 10;
    std::string line{"sample line"}
    PyObject* obj = PyUnicode_DecodeUTF8( line.c_str(), line.size(), "replace" );
    linecache.push_back( obj );
}

static PyObject* PyFastFile_iternext(PyFastFile* self, PyObject* args) {
    --counter;

    if( !( counter ) ) {
        PyErr_SetNone( PyExc_StopIteration );
        return NULL;
    }

    PyObject* retval = linecache[0];
    Py_XINCREF( retval );
    return retval;
}

// create the module
PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_fastfilepackage(void) {
    PyFastFileType.tp_iter = (getiterfunc) PyFastFile_tp_iter;
    PyFastFileType.tp_iternext = (iternextfunc) PyFastFile_iternext;
    PyFastFileType.tp_dealloc = (destructor) PyFastFile_dealloc;
    ...
}
```

On this case,

1. Is the `tp_next()` returning an owned reference to `linecache[0]` because it is incrementing its `Py_XINCREF`?
2. Meaning, is my `linecache[0]` cache now a borrowed reference?
3. As `tp_next()` is being called more than once, and I am returning the same pointer several times incrementing its `Py_XINCREF`, is this going to lead to double/triple/several frees?
4. Has the `tp_next()` return object only one owned reference, which will lead to double/triple/several?

---

Related:

1. [Py_INCREF/DECREF: When](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657764/py-incref-decref-when)

Comment: do you want c++ answer? `shared_ptr` maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need the reference count of an object to be equal to the number of `PyObject*` that refer to it.

1. Yes - you return a `PyObject*` to your Python code so you should increment the reference count.
2. No - when `linecache[0]` is created it has a refcount of 1 and this represents ownership by `linecache`. Multiple places can "own" a single Python object.
3. Yes you are returning the same pointer multiple times; no this will not result in multiple frees. The pointer is freed when the reference count reaches 0. This will be when you break all the references to the values you've returned from `next`, and when you lose the reference in `linecache` (when `PyFastFile_dealloc` is called).
4. I don't understand the last question, but the code here is basically correct.

---

The one issue I can see here is "what is `linecache`/who owns it". If it's a global variable then it may end up being shared between multiple `PyFastFile` objects which is probably wrong. The destruction of a single `PyFastFile` will lead to the entire `linecache` being freed, but you don't `pop_back` or `NULL` the pointers.