Python's C-extension with numpy randomly crashes after a few calls (5~10) from python code
To speed up custom MFCC calculations, I had to write some code in C, wrap it with Python's C API & numpy's C API, and compile it with disutils.core in order to import it from python code.
I was able to successfully compile, and execute, the code from python using a small sample.
However, once I called the same function with the same input ~10 times in a row using timeit OR a for loop, Python stopped without giving any error messages.
I don't think it's due to a memory leak, as the input data is 150kB, and I had gigabytes of spare RAM at the time.
The most baffling thing? It works when the function is called once or twice. It always seems to crash when called in the double digits.
Here is my code, reproduced:
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "CMel.h"


typedef struct{
    int real, imag;
} COMPLEX;

static PyMethodDef CMelMethods[] = {
    {"mel_40", mel_40, METH_VARARGS},
    {NULL, NULL}
};

static PyModuleDef CMelModule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT, "CMel", "Python interface for C-code of integer-based Mel Spectrogram calculation", -1, CMelMethods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_CMel(void) {
    import_array();
    return PyModule_Create(&CMelModule);
}

static PyObject* mel_40(PyObject* self, PyObject* args) {
    /* Input: numpy array (nparrayin)
    *  Output: numpy array (nparrayout)
    *  Function: performs mel-spectrogram transformation of given pcm-style array
    *            Always assumes samplerate=16000, framelength=480, hoplength=240, coefficients=40
    */

    PyArrayObject* nparrayin, * nparrayout;
    int* carrayin, * carrayout;
    int numframes;

    // Check i/o types, throw error if something is wrong
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O!", &PyArray_Type, &nparrayin))  {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "[mel_40] Input array type mismatch!");
        return NULL;
        }
    
    if (nparrayin == NULL)  {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "[mel_40] Input array is NULL");
        return NULL;
        }
    if (!is_intvector(nparrayin)) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "[is_intvector] Input array must be of type int16 or int32");
        return NULL;
        }

    // Copy numpy array to C array
    if (nparrayin->descr->type_num == NPY_INT16) {      // this is usually called
        carrayin = pyarray_int16_to_carrayptr_int32(nparrayin);
    }
    else { // if (nparrayin->descr->type_num == NPY_INT32) 
        carrayin = pyarray_int32_to_carrayptr_int32(nparrayin);
    }
    numframes = calculate_numframes(nparrayin->dimensions[0]);

    if (numframes <= 5) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "[mel_40] Input data is too short");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Operate on arrays here
    carrayout = (int*)malloc((numframes - 5) * 40 * sizeof(int));
    Calculate_Melspectrogram(carrayin, carrayout, numframes - 5);

    // Create nparrayout for outputting to python
    const npy_intp dims[2] = {numframes-5, 40};
    nparrayout = (PyArrayObject*)PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(2, dims, NPY_INT32, carrayout);

    free(carrayin);
    // Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657764/py-incref-decref-when
    Py_DECREF(nparrayin);
    return PyArray_Return(nparrayout);
}

int is_intvector(PyArrayObject *inputarray) {
    if (inputarray->descr->type_num != NPY_INT16 && inputarray->descr->type_num != NPY_INT32 || inputarray->nd != 1) return 0;
    return 1;
}

int* pyarray_int16_to_carrayptr_int32(PyArrayObject* inputarray) {
    // (int16) Numpy array -> (int32) C Array
    short* pyarray = (short*)inputarray->data;
    int* carray;
    int i, rows;

    rows = inputarray->dimensions[0];

    carray = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * rows);

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        carray[i] = (int)pyarray[i];
    }
    return carray;
}

int* pyarray_int32_to_carrayptr_int32(PyArrayObject* inputarray) {
    // (int32) Numpy array -> (int32) C Array
    int* pyarray = (int*)inputarray->data;
    int* carray;
    int i, rows;

    rows = inputarray->dimensions[0];

    carray = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * rows);

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        carray[i] = pyarray[i];
    }
    return carray;
}

int calculate_numframes(int numdata) {
    return ((numdata - 240) / 240);
}


void Calculate_Melspectrogram(int *inputarray, int *outputarray, int numframes) {
    COMPLEX *fftarray = (COMPLEX*)malloc(257 * sizeof(COMPLEX));
    int* window = (int*)calloc(514, sizeof(int));
    
    inputarray += 480;

    for (int i=0; i<numframes; i++) {
        memcpy(window, inputarray, 480 * sizeof(int));
        inputarray += 240;
        MFCC_Extract(window, fftarray);
        memcpy(outputarray, window, 40 * sizeof(int));
        outputarray += 40;
        
        //Reset fftarray
        memset(fftarray, 0, 257 * sizeof(COMPLEX));
        memset(window, 0, 514 * sizeof(int));
    }

    free(window);
    free(fftarray);
}

The function is called like so:
import numpy as np
import scipy.io.wavfile as wavfile
import timeit
from CMel import mel_40

samplerate, data = wavfile.read("./example.wav")

print(timeit.Timer(lambda: mel_40(data)).timeit(number=100))

The C code is compiled using the following:
python3 setup.py install
setup.py:
import os
import numpy as np
from sysconfig import get_paths
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

python_paths = get_paths()

CMelModule = Extension("CMel", define_macros=[('MAJOR_VERSION', '1'), ("MINOR_VERSION", "0")],
                       include_dirs=["/usr/local/include", os.path.join(np.get_include(), "numpy"), python_paths['include']],
                    #    libraries=["python36"],
                    #    library_dirs=[python_paths['stdlib']],
                       sources=["CMel.c", "melcalculations.c"])


def main():
    setup(name="CMel",
          version="1.0.0",
          description="Python interface for integer-based FFT and Mel Spectogram calculation",
          author="FB",
          author_email="FB@gmail.com",
          ext_modules=[CMelModule])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Note, MFCC_Extract() is where the MFCC extraction happens. It is too long to post here, but I have made sure it is working correctly, with no memory allocations happening inside of it.
Also, strangely enough, I have tried writing the contents of the output of mel_40 function to a file, and this gets it to work past the ~10 crash threshold.

"Python stopped without giving any error messages" Stopped where? At which line of code? Did you try to investigate it?

@Jeyekomon In the timeit example, it stopped at the timeit line, and failed to execute the lines after it (checked with both print() and debugging mode).
In other use cases, sometimes it stops at mel_40(), and other times it stops when accessing the numpy array created by mel_40

@Jeyekomon So... I just found out that PY_DECREF(nparrayin) dereferences the input array inside python as well. This may be the cause of my issue in the "other use cases", I will check further before posting.

I would personally add several assert to be sure the sizes are 100% correct (eg. Numpy array and allocated arrays) and then use GDB to track the problem. It is likely a segfault, buffer-overflow and/or double free.

Not related to the crash, but I'd recommend using the Python buffer protocol to access array data rather than directly interacting with Numpy structs.

Doing Py_DECREF(nparrayin) at the end of mel_40() is incorrect. In reference to PyArg_ParseTuple(), the Python extension docs say:

Note that any Python object references which are provided to the caller are borrowed references; do not decrement their reference count!

Here's some code that prints the refcount of the input array after each call to mel_40(), and the output with and without the decref:
import sys
import numpy as np
from CMel import mel_40

data = np.arange(0, (5 + 5)*240 + 240, dtype=np.int16)
# add a couple extra references
data_1 = data_2 = data

print("initial refcount:", sys.getrefcount(data))
for i in range(5):
    result = mel_40(data)
    print("refcount:", sys.getrefcount(data))

With Py_DECREF(nparrayin):
initial refcount: 4
refcount: 3
refcount: 2
double free or corruption (top)
[1]    753324 IOT instruction (core dumped)  python test.py

Without:
initial refcount: 4
refcount: 4
refcount: 4
refcount: 4
refcount: 4
refcount: 4

